# How can I show and hide a button after click?

Tags: javascript, html, button, hide

I tried this:

```
<button onclick="button_onclick()">Click me</button>
```

js:

```
button_onclick() = "this.style.visibility = 'hidden';"
```

Comment: <button onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">Hide</button>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```js
function button_onclick() {
 document.getElementById("btn").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="button_onclick()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error in `visibility` and this is not how you [define functions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-define-functions-in-javascript) in javascript.

You also need to pass down the element reference down as a parameter of the function.

```js
function button_onclick(element) {
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="button_onclick(this)">Click me</button>
```

**OR** with inline js:

```html
<button onclick="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems:

1. you're calling `button_onclick()` as a function but it's not [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) as one.
2. using inline `onclick` is no good
3. you've misspelled `visibality`. You should use `visibility` instead.

If you want to handle events. the best way is to attach an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the element.

```js
const myButton = document.querySelector('.my-button')

myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myButton.style.visibility = 'hidden'
})
```

```html
<button class="my-button">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easest way of doing

```html
<button onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">Click me</button>
```

> **Note**  this way of doing is not a good practice 
>   So do it in this way

```html
<button id="btn"> Click me </button>
<script>
const btn = document.querySelector ('#btn');
btn.addEventListener ('click', () =>{
btn.style.display = "none"
// btn.style.visibility = "hidden"
})

</script>
```

**Thank you**